# How can I filter data from a large corpus using a shell script?

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to extract tweets from a big twitter corpus, filtered on a specific location the tweet is tweeted. After that, I want to search in the tweets for a specific word. I have a command to list all tweets  as a tsv file:
`$ zless location/of/tweets.out.gz | /net/corpora/twitter2/tools/tweet2tab -i user.location text`

This gave me the following output, with a tab seperated:
`user.location      tweet`

Now, I want to only list for instance tweets from `location: Amsterdam`.
And after this, search for the `word: hallo` in all the tweets from Amsterdam. What is the best way to approach this problem using a shell script?

Comment: Is the original data by any chance in JSON format? It would be nearly trivial to query it with `jq` for exactly what you are looking for in that case, given that the document structure is known.

Comment: It is indeed in JSON format. However, it is standing on a external SSH, where I can not add the module jq. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Well, `jq` [is distributed](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) as a static binary with no library dependencies, so it would be easy to [just download it](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) into your home directory and use it from there. It would also be easy to transfer the data to any other place where you could install `jq` properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have come a lot further.
This is what I got now: ```location/of/tweets.out.gz | jq '. |
select( .user.location != null) | 
select ( .user.location | contains("Amsterdam")) | 
select(.text | contains ("[word to search]"))'```. However, I am stuck now since i dont want it to be  case sensitive. 
Another problem I face is that i don't know how to count the amount of hits on this command line.

Comment: You may want to either update your current question or write a new one.